# How can I add an incrementing id="" attribute to the following JavaScript generated HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have managed to come up with the following JavaScript and HTML but now I am stuck. I want to be able to add an id="" attribute to the fields and have them numbered as I add more fields with the '+ Add' button.

I've been playing around with this but have not had any success yet. Could someone give me some suggestions or offer some solutions to this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><table width="100%"><tr><td><input type="text" 
        name="field_name[]" value="" class="form-control" style="width:98%;" 
        placeholder="Role"/></td><td><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="" 
        class="form-control" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Name"/></td></tr></table> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 18px;"> - 
        Remove </button></a></div>';


    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < maxField){
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        }
    });

    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
```

```html
<label style="margin-top:70px;">Credits</label>
<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
      <table width='100%'>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="" placeholder="Role" class='form-control' style="width:98%"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="" placeholder="Name" class='form-control' style="width:100%"/>
          </td>
        </table>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">
          <button style='margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px;' type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> + Add Role </button>
        </a>

      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, had to tidy up your code to see what was going on

Answer (score 1):

You can try this snippet:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    var idCounter = 0;
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper

    function fieldHTML(id) {
      return '<div><table width="100%"><tr><td>id:' + id + '<input type="text"' +
        'id="role-' + id + '" name = "field_name[]" value = "" class="form-control" style = "width:98%;"' +
        'placeholder = "Role" /></td > <td><input type="text" id="name-' + id + '" name="field_name[]" value=""' +
        'class="form-control" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Name" /></td></tr ></table >' +
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><button type="button"' +
        'class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 18px;"> - Remove </button></a></div >';
    }

    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function () {
      //Check maximum number of input fields
      if (x < maxField) {
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML(idCounter++)); //Add field html
        x++; //Increment field counter
      }
    });

    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
      x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
  });
</script>


<label style="margin-top:70px;">Credits</label>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <table width='100%'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="" placeholder="Role" class='form-control' style="width:98%" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="" placeholder="Name" class='form-control' style="width:100%" />
        </td>
    </table>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><button
        style='margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px;' type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> + Add Role
      </button></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Note, I have created a new variable `idCounter` to keep the id unique even when you remove a row. Otherwise, it might create elements with duplicate ids.

This is just one quick way, but there are many other ways this can be achieved. The code can be made mode tidy and readable.